# Download artifacts in Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, artifacts, azure-artifacts

I get an error 'There is not enough space on the disk' during download artifacts from CloudVault.
Is it possible to increase the size of memory for artifacts that can be downloaded by task 'Download Artifacts - CloudVault' in Release pipeline?
If not, are there simple ways to download a few different subfolders from CloudVault?

Comment: there is a `patterns` property on the Download Artifact task, did you try to use it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops

Comment: (I hope i am not misunderstanding the issue)

Comment: Do you use a self-hosted agent? Have you checked whether there is enough space on your build agent machine?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no enough space on the disk where need to download the artifact. You need to check the disk space and clean the space on the machine, to make sure there is enough space to get the artifact.

Also, if you want to download a few different subfolders of pipeline artifacts using [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) from earlier stages in this pipeline, or from another pipeline, you could try `Matching Patterns`:

[image]